# How I can save the Skype chat history from my iPad?

Tags: ipad, skype, history, chat

How I can save the Skype chat history from my ipad?
It does not matter in what format, for example as a text file.

In my ipad, I have a chat history, which is very important for me. This chat history includes several years of communication (so to copy it manually is extremely difficult, because it is impossible to select and copy a large amount of text in Skipe on an iPad, but only one message at a time). I still don't update from iOS 6.1.3, in order to avoid losing this chat history. I can not find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice if Skype (Microsoft) synched the message history from your iDevices to your Mac where it is easily accessible, but I suspect they don't.

In the meanwhile you can try a trial version of something like iExplorer (https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) which can access most/all files created on iDevices and try to locate your Skype message history.

Comment: Thank you very much! Using iExplorer I transferred all Skype files, from an Ipad to my Imac, now I need to figure out how to find among them a file with the chat history and how to save it as text. But anyway, if the chat history is stored in these files, now I have a backup, thank you!